# Garbage image from xcomposite pixmap

Tags: x11

I'm using XComposite extension to get contents of the windows running under a sort of window manager that I develop. I found that in many cases if I try to get contents of the window using pixmap created with XCompositeNameWindowPixmap shortly after it was mapped and redirected I get garbage image from the pixmap. Same call a little bit later gives perfectly valid image of the window.

My assumption is that it takes some time to initially populate the pixmap. Unfortunately, I'm not able to quantify how much more time I have to wait before I can get correct image.

Is there any way to determine if composited pixmap is ready to be used? Or is there anything else that might be causing this weird effect?

Answer (score 2):

What you're experiencing is, that after redirecting a window the program has to redraw the window's contents, to those are not initially available right after redirection.

This is where the Damage extension enters the stage, which allows clients to inform other clients, that their window's contents have been updated.